# Revit group - cobies data with interoperability tool

Tags: revit-api

How to use interoperability tool with revit to add cobie parameters and avoid revit to recreate the groups?

Does create all the parameteres before creting the group helpful to avoid the above issue?

What are the other option?

I have tried to push the parameteres with interoperability tool but there only to option on is removing all the group the other is renaming all the group.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.